# Grouping month in a json file

Tags: python

I have a json file with articles from newspapers. Each row contains the date of the article, the title and the body. I want to create a count of months in which certain keywords appeared a text. So far I can only print the entire date , but I would like the retrieved the count of months: For example instead of January, January, January; something that would produce the count: January = 3 or something similar. My code so far looks like this one:

```
# import json module for parsing
import json
import re

# define a list of keywords
keywords = ('tax', 'Tax', 'policy', 'Policy',  'regulation', 'Regulation', 
 'spending', 'Spending', 'budget', 'Budget', 'oil', 'Oil',
 'Holyrood', 'holyrood', 'Scottish parliament', 'Scottish Parliament', 'scottish parliament' )

with open('Aberdeen2005.json') as json_file:

    # read json file line by line
    for line in json_file.readlines():
        json_dict = json.loads(line)

        if any(keyword in json_dict["body"].lower() for keyword in keywords):
            print(json_dict['date'].split()[0])
```

Comment: If you lower the dictionary value, then why store the capitalized versions in your keywords?

Comment: There is no need for regex here, you can use `split` and take the first element of the output list. Something like this: `json_dict['date'].split()[0]`

Comment: @cricket_007 What do you mean by storing capitalized versions in the keywords? Originally they had spaces but I saw that some keywords did not appeared: e.g. pre-tax.

Comment: Please don't include output as a screenshot. Put it directly into your question.

Comment: `keywords = ('tax', 'Tax', 'policy', 'Policy'...` You only need to store the lowercase words `keywords = ('tax', 'policy',`

Comment: Also, please add a sample of the JSON to your question if you want to have someone test their answer

Comment: You are working far too hard!  Store the data in a database and then use the database engine to answer questions like this.  You will have to learn SQL, but that will quickly payoff

Comment: @ravenspoint - Pretty sure pandas could also do it

Comment: @cezar great answer. Do you know how can I group them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this with Pandas:

```
import pandas
import json

# note if this actually works your json file is not correctly formed
df = pandas.DataFrame([json.loads(l) for l in open('Aberdeen2005.json')])

# Parse dates and set index
df.date = pandas.to_datetime(df.date)
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

# match keywords
matchingbodies = df[df.body.str.contains("|".join(keywords))].body

# Count by month
counts = matchingbodies.groupby(lambda x: x.month).agg(len)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is just a sample since you didn't provide what the JSON file looked like

```
import re

months = ('January', 
         'February', 
         'March', 
         'April',
         'May', 
         'June', 
         'July',
         'August',
         'September',
         'October',
         'November',
         'December')

file_content = '''
December 29, 2005 Thursday
December 15, 2005 Thursday
April 21, 2005
April 6, 2005
January 19, 2005
January 19, 2005
January 11, 2005
'''

d = {m:0 for m in months}

for line in file_content.splitlines():
    if line != '':
        # filter out empty strings from the split
        data = list(filter(lambda x: x != '', re.split('[,\s+]', line)))
        d[data[0]] += 1 # Grouping

print(d)
print(d['January'])
```

Output

```
{'August': 0, 'July': 0, 'November': 0, 'December': 2, 'April': 2, 'May': 0, 'October': 0, 'January': 3, 'September': 0, 'June': 0, 'March': 0, 'February': 0}
3
```

Comment: Looks good the code but I do not understand where can I insert it.... What about using the code that I already produce and making the minor changes as possible? Cheers,

Comment: Like I said, provide a sample of your JSON. You already are able to get the string that looks like `file_content` based on your question. My `line` is your `json_dict['date']`